# Setting NODE_PATH in Cloud9 IDE

Tags: cloud9-ide

!Short version: How can I set the NODE_PATH environment variable in a Cloud9 workspace?

Detail:
I'm trying to get MeanJS set up in a Cloud9 workspace. I first use nvm to upgrade Node from 0.10 to 0.12. Apparently, nvm doesn't set the NODE_PATH variable, so when I try to install Yo, I get an error. But I can't figure out how to set the NODE_PATH, or what the value should be.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can set NODE_PATH by editing ~/.bashrc file same way as on any other linux system.
Home folder is hidden by default, but can be shown using gear menu at the top of the tree.